# Android - Paged ListActivity that pages on horizontal swipe

Tags: android, listactivity, swipe, runnable, onfling

I have a list activity that implements Runnable so that my data fetch is done with a progress bar.  The data is pulled from a web service.  Right now, I go get all of the users, but I would like to change it so it retrieves the users one page at a time, instead of all at once.

```
public class ActiveUsersActivity extends ProtectedListActivity implements Runnable {
    ProgressDialog progress;
    ArrayList<UserModel> users;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        progress = ProgressDialog.show(ActiveUsersActivity.this, "", "Loading...", true);

        Thread thread = new Thread(ActiveUsersActivity.this);
        thread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
    //Get user data
    users = MyService.GetAllUsers();
    }
}
```

So, the modifications I need to make are to change run to get one page at a time.  That is easy enough, but my problem lies in how to do the actual horizontal swipe.  Ideally, I would like to make the list slide left or right like the home screens do when you do a swipe.  Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the swiping, have you looked at the [GestureDetector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.html)?  Check out the OnGestureListener and its onFling.